# Stripe credit card updates and customer service any good?

Tags: contributions, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, stripe

We're seriously considering switching form PayPal to Stripe because PayPal's customer service is outright horrible (e.g. three times now they have simply closed our support case without any resolution or explanation... just... closed it) and because they're not updating expired credit cards on subscriptions/recurring payments.

The switch would be slightly more costly for us due to the fact that:

- Stripe doesn't revert the fees for refunds (i.e. they pocket them;
  PayPal keeps the $0.49 static fee, but reverts the 1.99% fee)
- Their fees are slightly higher (based on our transactions for the past 12 months, their fee structure would end up costing us slightly more)

Therefore, we're trying to make sure the switch is worth the effort - so MY QUESTIONS:

1. How do you find Stripe's customer service?
2. Have you seen a decent update rate for expired credit cards? (I'm referring to the automatic update they get from the banks, not the manual update done by the card owner or your admin staff)
3. Any other drawbacks we should be aware of with Stripe?

Thank you so much for any insights on the three items above.

Comment: I can't really answer your three points, so a comment instead.  +1 for walking away from PayPal!   They've gone from providing a simple, clearly defined service to a bloated sales company fill with jargon.  Technically speaking Stripe is MUCH easier to deal with.  Also, consider iATS?

Comment: There is a Stripe channel where you may get other eyeballs on your question https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/stripe

Comment: thank you, Eliot and Pete, for your comments; we've used iATS in the past, and weren't totally enamored (back in the day, they had limited reporting capabilities, etc., so maybe I should give them a look-see again); I'll go check out the channel now